# Duplicate values ​in reusable custom <select>

Tags: javascript, html

There is a page on which there are two identical custom selects. The problem is the duplication of the selected data. When clicking on the label in the second select, the selected value is substituted in the second and the first select. In the console, first click on the selected select -> the value is written to the input, then there is a click on another select -> the value is written to the input. + all previous iterations are displayed in the console. The first select is in the My Purchases tab, the second select is in the My Points tab. If I select "Yesterday" in the select, then this value is entered in all selects.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26lKa.png)

```
<!-- Calendar for filtering checks by date -->
<div class="calendar__main d-fl">
    <div class="calendar__wrapper d-fl-col">
        <label class="calendar__label js-calendarLabelError">Необходимо выбрать дату</label>
        <input type="text" class="calendar__input js-calendar__input" readonly placeholder="Выберите дату">
        <div class="select__calendar-content js-selectContent d-fl-col">
            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect0" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect0" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="yestrday">Вчера</label>

            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect1" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect1" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="last-week">Неделю назад</label>

            <input type="radio" id="singleSelect2" class="select__calendar-input" name="singleSelect">
            <label for="singleSelect2" class="select__option select__calendar-label js-select__option" data-calendar-time="last-month">Месяц назад</label>

            <input type="text" class="select__option js-calendarDateRange" id="calendar__date-picker" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" data-language='ru' placeholder="Выбрать дату" name="calendar-check">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn__calendar js-showCalendarDate">Показать</button>
</div>



// function to select option
  function chooseCalendarDate() {
    let calendarInput = document.querySelectorAll(".js-calendar__input"); // input in which the selected option will be
    let radioBtnCalendarLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".js-select__option"); // 
label on which click occurs to select data
    let calendarDateRange = document.querySelector(".js-calendarDateRange"); // input on which the calendar opens

    // when you click on the input, the content with the option is opened
    calendarInput.forEach((inputCalendar, index) => {
      inputCalendar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const mainContent = document.querySelector(".main_content");
        inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active"); // content with option
        mainContent.classList.add("active");

        // closing content on option click + data selection
        radioBtnCalendarLabel.forEach((labelBtn) => {
          labelBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            inputCalendar.value = e.target.textContent; // put new data in input
            inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active"); // content with option

            console.log(e.target);
            console.log(inputCalendar.value, inputCalendar, index);
          });
        });

        // closing content when clicking on an empty space
        mainContent.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          if (e.target !== inputCalendar && e.target !== calendarDateRange) {
            if (calendarDateRange.value.length > 0) {
              inputCalendar.value = calendarDateRange.value; // put new data in input
              calendarDateRange.value = ""; // reset the data for further opening
            }
            mainContent.classList.remove("active");
            inputCalendar.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active"); // content with option
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
  chooseCalendarDate();
```